# Get the data of Date and pass it from another page using jquery/javascript/php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I was hopeless to solve this :(

Can you help me to figure out this :( I debug for a wholeday but nothing gonna change.
i have two php file which is the index.php and home.php

inside the index.php include the Date which is the daterangepicker and my concern is.
imagine in index.php I want to pass the Date of Daterangepicker and send to home.php.

I want to load the Date in home.php. something like that
here's my code hope you get my point. I'm really sorry

should i use php session? or localstorage ?
I have an example output shown in image below
[image: index.php]

[image: home.php]

and here's i want to achieved...

disclaimer: the gif you see is the output that i want to achieved...
[image: Output]

**This is my code in index.php**

```
            <!DOCTYPE html>
            <html lang="en">
            <head>
                <meta charset="UTF-8">
                <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
                <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
                <title>1st Page</title>
                <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-+0n0xVW2eSR5OomGNYDnhzAbDsOXxcvSN1TPprVMTNDbiYZCxYbOOl7+AMvyTG2x" crossorigin="anonymous">
                <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.css" />
                <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js" integrity="sha256-H+K7U5CnXl1h5ywQfKtSj8PCmoN9aaq30gDh27Xc0jk=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
                <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/526540c6e4.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/latest/moment.min.js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.min.js"></script>
                <script src="script.js"></script>
            </head>
            <body>

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-12 col-lg-4 offset-lg-4">
                    <h3  class="text-center">1st page</h3>
                        <form action="home.php" method="post">
                            <div id="reportrange" class="form-control form-control-lg text-center form-group " tabindex="2" style="background: #fff; cursor: pointer; ">
                                <i class="fa fa-fw fa-calendar fa-lg text-muted"></i>&nbsp;<span id="span_booked"></span>     
                            </div> 
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-block" onclick="passvalues();">Submit</button>     
                        </form>    
                    </div>
                </div>
                <script>
                    function passvalues(){
                        var firstname = document.getElementById('reportrange').value;
                        localStorage.setItem("txt_data",firstname);
                        return false;
                    }
                </script>
            </body>
            </html>
```

**and here's my code in home.php**

```
            <!DOCTYPE html>
            <html lang="en">
            <head>
                <meta charset="UTF-8">
                <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
                <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
                <title>2nd Page</title>
                <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-+0n0xVW2eSR5OomGNYDnhzAbDsOXxcvSN1TPprVMTNDbiYZCxYbOOl7+AMvyTG2x" crossorigin="anonymous">
                <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.css" />
                <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js" integrity="sha256-H+K7U5CnXl1h5ywQfKtSj8PCmoN9aaq30gDh27Xc0jk=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
                <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/526540c6e4.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
                <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-IQsoLXl5PILFhosVNubq5LC7Qb9DXgDA9i+tQ8Zj3iwWAwPtgFTxbJ8NT4GN1R8p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
                <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Atwg2Pkwv9vp0ygtn1JAojH0nYbwNJLPhwyoVbhoPwBhjQPR5VtM2+xf0Uwh9KtT" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>    
                <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/latest/moment.min.js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.min.js"></script>
                <script src="script2.js"></script>
            </head>
            <body>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-4 offset-4">
                <h3  class="text-center">2nd page</h3>
                    <div id="reportrange" class="form-control form-control-lg text-center form-group " tabindex="2" style="background: #fff; cursor: pointer; ">
                        <i class="fa fa-fw fa-calendar fa-lg text-muted"></i>&nbsp;<span id="span_booked"></span>     
                    </div>        
                </div>
            </div>

            </body>
            </html>
```

**and lastly, my javascript script code**

```
    $(function() {

    var string_date = new Date();
    var string_year = string_date.getFullYear() + 1;
    var date_today = moment().format('ddd, MMM D, YYYY');
    var max_date = moment().format('ddd, MMM D,' + string_year);

    var start = moment();
    var end = moment().add(1, 'days');

      function cb(start, end) {
        $('#reportrange #span_booked').html(start.format('ddd, MMM D') + ' - ' + end.format('ddd, MMM D')); // Date String Format example: Mon, May 24 - Tue, May 25
      }

      $('#reportrange').daterangepicker({
        startDate: start,
        endDate: end,
        minDate: date_today, // Minimum Date 
        maxDate: max_date, // Maximum Date is date today and +1 from this year
        maxSpan: { "days": 30 }, // the maximum days that the customer stay is 60 days only!
        locale: {
              cancelLabel: 'Close', 
              format: 'ddd, MMM D, YYYY',          
              monthNames: [
                          "January",
                          "February",
                          "March",
                          "April",
                          "May",
                          "June",
                          "July",
                          "August",
                          "September",
                          "October",
                          "November",
                          "December"
                      ]
          },
        opens: 'center',
        cancelClass: "btn btn-danger",
        applyButtonClasses: "btn btn-success"        
      }, cb);
      
      cb(start, end);

      $('#reportrange #span_booked').on('apply.daterangepicker', function(ev, picker) {
        $(this).val(picker.startDate.format('MM/DD/YYYY') + ' - ' + picker.endDate.format('MM/DD/YYYY'));
      });

      $('#reportrange #span_booked').on('cancel.daterangepicker', function(ev, picker) {
        $(this).val('');
      });

    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the form is submitting before the script gets a chance to set `localStorage`. The flow should be:

- user picks date
- user clicks submit
- javascript stops form from submitting - which is not what is happening now
- javascript sets key/value pair in localStorage
- javascript allows form to submit to home.php, where you can pick up the value from `localStorage`

In this case, suspend form submission with `onsubmit` handler, like this:

```
<form action="home.php" method="post" onsubmit='return passvalues()' >
```

and passvalues() looks like this:

```
function passvalues(){
  var firstname = document.getElementById('span_booked').innerHTML; // datepicker is writing the chosen value to this element 
  if (firstname=='') {
    alert('Please choose a date range');
    return false; // prevent form submission
  }
  localStorage.setItem("txt_data",firstname);
  return true; // allow form to submit
}
```

On home.php, I think you want to put the value in `#span_booked` rather than rewrite the innerHTML of `display_date`

```
<script>
  document.getElementById('span_booked').innerHTML = localStorage.getItem('txt_data');
</script>
```

Comment: Thank You very much, It seems my problem has been solved.

Comment: I convert the javascript into jquery code thanks for you Man hehehehhe

Comment: I hope this code will help the future programmers so i added some new updates heheheheh

Comment: Maybe i repost this again to help our fellow newbie programmers as well as me heheheheehhe